# Is this sentence wrong: "write a letter for me to teach in the university" and if so, why?

Tags: infinitives, subjects

Suppose I'm applying for a teaching position and asking someone for a reference letter. Then is it correct to say:

> Can you write a reference letter for me to teach in the university?

to mean "Can you write a reference letter so that I can teach in the university?"

My feeling is that it's wrong, though I cannot pinpoint the reason. I know there's a way to specify the subject of a to-infinitive with "for", but I still don't feel the subject of "to apply" can be specified with "for me", and the subject still seems to be "you", as in:

> Can you write a reference letter to allow me to teach in the university?

Can someone clarify the correctness and the reason? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "...to support my application for a [teaching] post at the university"?

Comment: *...Write a course for me to teach in the university* seems more natural. Or put the purpose/reason at the start.